# Spring Data JPA - Lazy Loaded collection fetched without @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

My expectation is that a lazy loaded collection should be fetched when the collection is accessed within a transactional scope.  For example, if I want to fetch a collection I can call `foo.getBars.size()`.  The absence of an active transaction should result in an exception with an error message like

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of bars: .... could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session

However, I noticed that the behavior is different in my latest application.  I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.1 with the "data-jpa" starter. I have used Spring Boot in the past, but the data-jpa starter is new for me.

Consider the following case.  I have a lazy loaded ManyToMany collection.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo implements java.io.Serializable {
    ....
    private Set<Bar> bars = new HashSet<Bar>(0);
    ....

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "foo_bar_map",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bar_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    public Set<Bar> getBars() {
        return this.bars;
    }

    public void setBar(Set<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }
```

My service method is NOT marked as Transactional but I am accessing a lazy loaded collection

```
@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepo;


    @Override
    public FooDTO findById(int fooId) {
        Foo foo = fooRepo.findOne(fooId);
        // The FooDTO constructor will access foo.getBars()  
        return new FooDTO(foo);
    }
```

And for context on the FooDTO constructor

```
public FooDTO(Foo foo) {
    ...
    for (Bar bar : foo.getBars()) {
        this.bars.add(bar);
    }
}
```

Contrary to my expectation and past experience, this code executes successfully and fetches the collection.  Further, if I throw a breakpoint in my service method, I can step through the code and see the SQL statements in my logs that fetch the bars after my call to the fooRepo. After my call to fooRepo, I expect the transaction to be closed.

What's happening here?

Comment: Who calls the service? My guess is that the caller is transactional.

Comment: @JBNizet The method is called by a controller which is not marked as transactional either....

Comment: Spring boot seems to use an OpenEntityManagerInViewwInterceptor by default: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaBaseConfiguration.java#L203. See also http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties (and search for OpenEntityManagerInView)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for digging that up.  That effectively answers my question.  If posted as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spring Boot uses an OpenEntityManagerInView interceptor by default. You can turn it off by setting the property `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to false.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) for the reference about this (and other) JPA properties.

Comment: It doesn't happen in all cases, why so?

Answer (score 3):

You could turn on logging to check if a Transaction is being opened.

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction
```

or

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransaction
```

Also, you could set a breakpoint and use this static method to check if a transaction is open.

```
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the @JoinTable