# Spring Data, JPA @OneToMany Lazy fetch not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

I have `@OneToMany` relationship between `FabricRoll` and `FabricDefect`.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fabric_roll_id", referencedColumnName = "fabric_roll_id")
private Set<FabricDefect> fabricDefects = new HashSet<>();
```

The problem is when I get `FabricRoll` by `JpaRepository` function

> findAll()

the associate `FabricDefect` is also loaded.

I want to load only `FabricRoll` and `FabricDefect` should load when calling the function `getFabricDefect()`

> FabricRollServiceImpl class

```
@Component
public class FabricRollServiceImpl implements IFabricRollService{
    @Autowired
    FabricRollRepository fabricRollRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    @Override
    public List<FabricRoll> getAllFabricRoll() {
        FabricRoll fabricRoll1 = new FabricRoll();
        fabricRoll1.setBatchNo("34344");
        fabricRoll1.setLotNo("425");
        fabricRoll1.setPoNo("42");
        fabricRoll1.setRollLength(2343);
        fabricRoll1.setRollNo("356");
        fabricRoll1.setRollWidth(60);
        fabricRoll1.setStyleNo("354");

        FabricDefect fabricDefect = new FabricDefect();
        fabricDefect.setDefectNote("note");
        fabricDefect.setDefectPoint(3);
        fabricDefect.setSegment(3);
        fabricDefect.setYard(42);


        Set<FabricDefect> fabricDefects = new HashSet<>();
        fabricDefects.add(fabricDefect);


        fabricRoll1.setFabricDefects(fabricDefects);

        addFabricRoll(fabricRoll1);

        FabricRoll fabricRoll = null;


        return fabricRollRepository.findAll();
    }

@Override
public void addFabricRoll(FabricRoll fabricRoll) {
    fabricRollRepository.save(fabricRoll);
}
```

}

Break point:
[image]

Console:
[image]

Comment: This is OneToMany, why you uesed JoinColumn ?

Comment: show what you have in `FabricDefect` class

Comment: if you get rid of the `@Transactional` annotation you will see that you'll get `LazyInitializationException` which means that the collection is not loaded.

Comment: here the answer for same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584774/5289288

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a debugging artifact.

At debugging time, because the transaction is still open, the watched lazy loaded entity properties will be loaded at the breakpoint evaluation time.

To check the "production" behavior you should insert a `em.detach` statement just before the breakpoint or use logging (as suggested by Manza) and check `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().isLoaded(fabricRoll1.fabricDefects())` returns false on the detached entity.

(remember to inject EntityManager for example by declaring `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `@JoinColumn`, and you don't need to instantiate fabricDefects

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<FabricDefect> fabricDefects ;
```

See more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811844/jpa-onetomany-and-manytoone-relationships/45613346) question.

Answer (score 0):

FabricDefect class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fabric_roll_id")
private FabricRoll roll;
```

FabricRoll class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "roll")
private Set<FabricDefect> fabricDefects;
```

Collections are by default loaded lazily, JPA will query the db only when the method `getFabricDefects` will be called.
You can see it by yourself enabling logging.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in [this tutorial](http://javasampleapproach.com/hibernate/use-hibernate-lazy-fetch-eager-fetch-type-spring-boot-mysql).

You have to modify `FabricRoll` `OneToMany` map as below:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fabricRoll")
private Set<FabricDefect> fabricDefects;
```

`FabricDefect` `ManyToOne` as below (remember to remove `fabric_roll_id` field if you included it in your entity):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fabric_roll_id")
private FabricRoll fabricRoll;
```

And you don't need to add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` before `getAllFabricRoll()` function.